# Best way to deploy user defined functions to multiple databases in SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, database

I manage a server with around 400+ databases which have the same database schema, i wish to deploy a custom clr/.net user defined function to them all, is there any *easy* way to do this, or must it be done individually to each database?

Best Regards, 
Wayne

Comment: This kind of question is typically better addressed at serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you create it in master (in MSSQL) it can be referenced from any other db in that instance.  Certainly seems to work for Stored Procs anyway.

I should add that this only works if the databases are all on the same server instance...

You could write a small app to deploy the udf to the master of each SQL server instance if all 400 reside on multiple servers.

Comment: This is currently what i am doing (after i posted the question).  I think its probably the best way to go i guess!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just find some way i think. Some kind of Inception ;)
USE data_base works only inner EXECUTE context, so...

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @innersql NVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE  c CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.databases

DECLARE @name nvarchar(1000)

OPEN c

SET @innersql = 'CREATE FUNCTION Foo(@x varchar(1)) RETURNS varchar(100) AS ' +
                '  BEGIN RETURN(@x + ''''some text'''') END;'
--                                   ^^^^         ^^^^
--         every (') must be converted to QUAD ('''') instead of DOUBLE('') !!!

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
-- create function must be the first statement in a query batch ???
-- ok, will be... in inner EXEC...
    SET @sql = 'USE [' + @name + ']; EXEC (''' + @innersql + ''');'

    --PRINT @sql

    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name
  END

CLOSE c

DEALLOCATE c
```

Ups, I missed "CLR/.NET" part reading question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i'd just create a dynamic script to create it on each database.  but after that i'd put it in the modal databases so that all new databases are created with it.

you could also use the same script to push out changes if the function ever gets modified.